# Type mismatch: inferred type is androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical but androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical was expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing below error, I am new in compose

> Type mismatch: inferred type is androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical
> but androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical was
> expected

Simply, I know package was mismatch as error.

Code

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Alignment.CenterVertically
        )
```

Anyone have idea how to fix it or why this error generate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `verticalArrangement` attribute in the `Column` requires a **`androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical`** value and you are using `androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical` (used by `verticalAlignment` in the `Row`).

Use:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
)
```

Comment: Ah, "Arrangement". Not "Alignment".